# Get-AzMarketplaceTerms : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell

Here is the script:-

```
$SourceSubscription = "--ENTER-SOURCE-SUBSCRIPTION-ID--"
$TargetSubscription = "--ENTER-TARGET-SUBSCRIPTION-ID--"


Clear
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $TargetSubscription -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose

#read marketplace vm details from the json file

$Filex = '.\MarketplaceVMs.json'
$MarkVMs = Get-Content -Raw -Path $Filex | ConvertFrom-Json


foreach($MarkVM in $MarkVMs){
    
    #Common Parameters
    $resourceGroupName = $MarkVM.ResourceGroupName
    $location = $MarkVM.Location
    $virtualMachineName = $MarkVM.Name
    $virtualMachineSize = $MarkVM.HardwareProfile.VmSize            
    $nics = $MarkVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
    $caching = $MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Caching


    #Create Marketplace VMs from managed disk
    if($MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk){
        
        $osDiskName = $MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name  
        $disk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $osDiskName 

 
        $VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $virtualMachineName -VMSize $virtualMachineSize 
        if($MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq 1){ 
            $VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Caching $caching -Linux
            "`nCreating Linux configuration..."
            }
        else{ 
            $VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Caching $caching -Windows
            "`nCreating Windows configuration..."
            }

        }


    #Create Marketplace VM from unmanaged disk
    if($MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd){
        
        $osDiskVhdUri = $MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri  
        $osDiskName = $MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
   
        $VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $virtualMachineName -VMSize $virtualMachineSize 
        if($MarkVM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq 1){ 
            $VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $osDiskName -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -CreateOption Attach -Caching $caching -Linux  
            "`nCreating Linux configuration"        
        }
        else{
            $VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $osDiskName -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -CreateOption Attach -Caching $caching -Windows
            "`nCreating Windows configuration"
        }
    }


     $VirtualMachine.Plan = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.Plan'
     $VirtualMachine.Plan.Name = $MarkVM.Plan.Name
     $VirtualMachine.Plan.Product = $MarkVM.Plan.Product
     $VirtualMachine.Plan.Publisher = $MarkVM.Plan.Publisher
     Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher $VirtualMachine.Plan.Publisher -Product $VirtualMachine.Plan.Product -Name $VirtualMachine.Plan.Name | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept 
  
     foreach($nic in $nics){
            if($nic.Primary){
                $VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $nic.Id.Replace($SourceSubscription,$TargetSubscription) -Primary 
            }else{ 
                $VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $nic.Id.Replace($SourceSubscription,$TargetSubscription)
            }
        }

     $Virtualmachine | ConvertTo-Json
     New-AzVM -VM $VirtualMachine -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -Verbose
     'Virtual machine('+ $MarkVM.Name +') creation complete...'
    
}
```

when i am running this script facing this error:

```
Creating Linux configuration...
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.MarketplaceOrdering\2.0.0\exports\ProxyCmdletDefinitions.ps1:537 char:9
+         $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzMarketplaceTerms_Get1], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.MarketplaceOrdering.Cmdlets.GetAzMarketplaceTerms_Get1
 
Set-AzMarketplaceTerms : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
At E:\DevOps Batch 3.0\Untitled1.ps1:70 char:6
+      Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher $VirtualMachine.Plan.Publisher ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AzMarketplaceTerms], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Set-AzMarketplaceTerms
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like `$MarkVM.Plan.Name` might be empty for at least one of the VMs in the json you're using :)